# Calling a Class or Method in C# using Mono

Tags: c#, class, methods, mono

I'm having some problems calling a class or method in C# using Mono, can anyone give some help on what I'm doing wrong?

I want this piece of code:

```
public static void Execute(ScriptHost host)
{
    try
    {
        TesteGUI teste = new TesteGUI(); //?
        TesteGUI(); // ?
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

To call this piece of code:

```
public TesteGUI(Gtk.Window parentWindow) : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    base.Modal = false;
    base.TransientFor = parentWindow;
    base.Decorated = false;
    base.WindowPosition = WindowPosition.CenterAlways;

    this.MyBuild();

    base.KeyReleaseEvent += delegate(object o, KeyReleaseEventArgs args)
                        {
                                if (args.Event.Key == Gdk.Key.Escape)
                                {
                                    this.Destroy();
                                }
                            };
}
```

What is my doing wrong and how can I make it work?

Thank you

Comment: You're trying to call a constructor, so you have to use the `new TesteGUI` way. However, you're missing a parameter - you have to pass the parent window to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
public static void Execute(ScriptHost host)
{
    try
    {
        TesteGUI teste = new TesteGUI(parentWindow); //where parentWindow is defined somewhere earlier and is of type Gtk.Window
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark it as answered as well so the question does not remain in the Unanswered category. Thanks!